# Почему переменная не изменяется в цикле?

Tags: python, datetime, while

Собственно вот код :

```
import schedule
import time

def time_csv():
    time_date = datetime.datetime.today()
    return time_date
time_date = time_csv()


while True:
    schedule.every(2).seconds.do(time_csv)
    print(time_date)
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(3)
```

А вот результат выполнения :

```
2020-07-11 14:40:31.429645
2020-07-11 14:40:31.429645
2020-07-11 14:40:31.429645
2020-07-11 14:40:31.429645
2020-07-11 14:40:31.429645
2020-07-11 14:40:31.429645
2020-07-11 14:40:31.429645
2020-07-11 14:40:31.429645
2020-07-11 14:40:31.429645
```

почему время берется только при первом старте функции?
как решить это ?
спасибо заранее.

Comment: Необходимо перед следующим вызовом обнулить переменную. Приравняй её к null

Comment: Вы печатаете результат первого выполнения этой функции, поэтому он и показывается. Попробуйте вместо `time_date` напечатать `time_csv()`.

Comment: Потому что чтобы переменная изменялась, нужно её изменять. А в коде этого нет. Значение ей присваивается только один раз.

Comment: ваша ошибка лежит в области видимости. изучите https://python-scripts.com/scope

Comment: @luc1f, что за чушь? Во-первых, в питоне нет null. Во-вторых, обнуление здесь никак не решает проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот пример бесконечного цикла с изменением времени

```
def time_csv():
    return datetime.datetime.today()

while True:
    print(time_csv())
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: я возможно не верно изначально начал мыслить . Дело в том что я планировал позже записывать данную  переменную в моем примере  в Data Frame

Comment: дело в том, что вы не изменяете значение переменной в цикле, а вызываете функцию print передавая в нее переменную time_date, которой ранее уже было присвоено значение. Что бы получить текущее время вы можете обновлять значение переменной в теле цикла.

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался с вашей помощью .

Answer (score 0):

Вы до цикла приравняли переменную time_date = time_csv(), а потом в самом цикле бесконечно её вызываете, поэтому она показывает постоянно одно значение. После функции time_date уже находится вне области видимости функции и ей постоянно присвоено одно значение. В вашем случае наверное гораздо проще в теле цикла принтом вызывать саму функцию, т.е print(time_csv()), как написал выше DD_N0p